# Creating complex environment variables

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Out of environment variable WORKSPACE I need to extract part of the string after last **'\'**. For example I have `something1\something2\something3` and I need to extract **something3** and save it as environment variable in Jenkinsfile.

I've tried this approach:

```
groovy
environment {
        service = "${(env.WORKSPACE).substring((env.WORKSPACE).lastIndexOf('\'), (env.WORKSPACE).length())}"
    }
```

But while running it I get an error:

```
WorkflowScript: 20: expecting ''', found '\n' @ line 20, column 113.
    (env.WORKSPACE).length())}"""
                                 ^

1 error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Groovy and many other languages, `\` is an escape character.  So in the lastIndexOf, the `'\'` is opening a string, then escaping the closing `'`

You just need to escape the `\` (escape the escape)

```
"${(env.WORKSPACE).substring((env.WORKSPACE).lastIndexOf('\\'), (env.WORKSPACE).length())}"
```

You can also take this out of a string, as it's already a string:

```
service = env.WORKSPACE.substring(env.WORKSPACE.lastIndexOf('\\'), env.WORKSPACE.length())
```

Should be enough

Comment: I've used the first solution and it worked great. Also I've had to add +1 to the beginning index